# 32 bit aplications aren't installing properly on 64-bit

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

I am using Debian 9 64-bit. I have been trying to get this to work for a while and I don't know exactly what is going on so I will just show what happens:

```
sudo aptitude install wine32
Note: selecting "wine32:i386" instead of the virtual package "wine32" The following NEW packages will be installed: i965-va-driver:i386{a} libasound2:i386{a} libasound2-plugins:i386{a} libasyncns0:i386{a} libavahi-client3:i386{a} libavahi-common3:i386{a} libavcodec57:i386{a} libavresample3:i386{a} libavutil55:i386{a} libbsd0:i386{a} libc6:i386{a} libcairo2:i386{a} libcap2:i386{a} libcomerr2:i386{a} libcrystalhd3:i386{a} libcups2:i386{a} libdb5.3:i386{a} libdbus-1-3:i386{a} libdrm-amdgpu1:i386{a} libdrm-intel1:i386{a} libdrm-nouveau2:i386{a} libdrm-radeon1:i386{a} libdrm2:i386{a} libedit2:i386{a} libelf1:i386{a} libexpat1:i386{a} libffi6:i386{a} libflac8:i386{a} libfontconfig1:i386{a} libfreetype6:i386{a} libgl1-mesa-dri:i386{a} libgl1-mesa-glx:i386{a} libglapi-mesa:i386{a} libglu1-mesa:i386{a} libgmp10:i386{a} libgnutls30:i386{a} libgomp1:i386{a} libgpm2:i386{a} libgsm1:i386{a} libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{a} libhogweed4:i386{a} libice6:i386{a} libicu57:i386{a} libidn11:i386{a} libjack-jackd2-0:i386{a} libjbig0:i386{a} libjpeg62-turbo:i386{a} libk5crypto3:i386{a} libkeyutils1:i386{a} libkrb5-3:i386{a} libkrb5support0:i386{a} liblcms2-2:i386{a} libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} libllvm3.9:i386{a} libltdl7:i386{a} liblzma5:i386{a} libmp3lame0:i386{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} libncurses5:i386{a} libnettle6:i386{a} libnuma1:i386{a} libodbc1:i386{a} libopenal1:i386{a} libopenjp2-7:i386{a} libopus0:i386{a} libosmesa6:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{a} libpcap0.8:i386{a} libpciaccess0:i386{a} libpcre3:i386{a} libpixman-1-0:i386{a} libpng16-16:i386{a} libpulse0:i386{a} libsamplerate0:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a} libsasl2-modules:i386{a} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} libselinux1:i386{a} libsensors4:i386{a} libshine3:i386{a} libsm6:i386{a} libsnappy1v5:i386{a} libsndfile1:i386{a} libsndio6.1:i386{a} libsoxr0:i386{a} libspeex1:i386{a} libspeexdsp1:i386{a} libssl1.1:i386{a} libstdc++6:i386{a} libswresample2:i386{a} libsystemd0:i386{a} libtasn1-6:i386{a} libtheora0:i386{a} libtiff5:i386{a} libtinfo5:i386{a} libtwolame0:i386{a} libtxc-dxtn-s2tc:i386{a} libuuid1:i386{a} libva-drm1:i386{a} libva-x11-1:i386{a} libva1:i386{a} libvdpau-va-gl1:i386{a} libvdpau1:i386{a} libvorbis0a:i386{a} libvorbisenc2:i386{a} libvpx4:i386{a} libwavpack1:i386{a} libwebp6:i386{a} libwebpmux2:i386{a} libwine:i386{a} libwrap0:i386{a} libx11-6:i386{a} libx11-xcb1:i386{a} libx264-148:i386{a} libx265-95:i386{a} libxau6:i386{a} libxcb-dri2-0:i386{a} libxcb-dri3-0:i386{a} libxcb-glx0:i386{a} libxcb-present0:i386{a} libxcb-render0:i386{a} libxcb-shm0:i386{a} libxcb-sync1:i386{a} libxcb1:i386{a} libxcomposite1:i386{a} libxcursor1:i386{a} libxdamage1:i386{a} libxdmcp6:i386{a} libxext6:i386{a} libxfixes3:i386{a} libxi6:i386{a} libxinerama1:i386{a} libxml2:i386{a} libxrandr2:i386{a} libxrender1:i386{a} libxshmfence1:i386{a} libxslt1.1:i386{a} libxtst6:i386{a} libxvidcore4:i386{a} libxxf86vm1:i386{a} libzvbi0:i386{a} mesa-va-drivers:i386{a} mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{a} uuid-runtime{a} va-driver-all:i386{a} vdpau-driver-all:i386{a} wine32:i386 zlib1g:i386{a} The following packages will be upgraded: libavcodec57 libavresample3 libavutil55 libicu57 liblcms2-2 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common libssl1.1 libswresample2 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libwavpack1 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcursor1 The following partially installed packages will be configured: libgcc1:i386 15 packages upgraded, 149 newly installed, 0 to remove and 194 not upgraded. Need to get 0 B/95.6 MB of archives. After unpacking 480 MB will be used. The following packages have unmet dependencies: libx11-xcb-dev : Depends: libx11-xcb1 (= 2:1.6.4-3) but 2:1.6.4-3+deb9u1 is to be installed libvorbisfile3 : Depends: libvorbis0a (= 1.3.5-4) but 1.3.5-4+deb9u2 is to be installed libxcursor-dev : Depends: libxcursor1 (= 1:1.1.14-1+deb9u1) but 1:1.1.14-1+deb9u2 is to be installed libx11-dev : Depends: libx11-6 (= 2:1.6.4-3) but 2:1.6.4-3+deb9u1 is to be installed open: 41; closed: 730; defer: 6; conflict: 6 The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

 Upgrade the following packages:                                                             

1) libvorbisfile3 [1.3.5-4 (, now) -> 1.3.5-4+deb9u2 (stable)]
2) libx11-dev [2:1.6.4-3 (, now) -> 2:1.6.4-3+deb9u1 (stable)]
3) libx11-xcb-dev [2:1.6.4-3 (, now) -> 2:1.6.4-3+deb9u1 (stable)]
4) libxcursor-dev [1:1.1.14-1+deb9u1 (, now) -> 1:1.1.14-1+deb9u2 (stable)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y 
The following NEW packages will be installed: i965-va-driver:i386{a} libasound2:i386{a} libasound2-plugins:i386{a} libasyncns0:i386{a} libavahi-client3:i386{a} libavahi-common3:i386{a} libavcodec57:i386{a} libavresample3:i386{a} libavutil55:i386{a} libbsd0:i386{a} libc6:i386{a} libcairo2:i386{a} libcap2:i386{a} libcomerr2:i386{a} libcrystalhd3:i386{a} libcups2:i386{a} libdb5.3:i386{a} libdbus-1-3:i386{a} libdrm-amdgpu1:i386{a} libdrm-intel1:i386{a} libdrm-nouveau2:i386{a} libdrm-radeon1:i386{a} libdrm2:i386{a} libedit2:i386{a} libelf1:i386{a} libexpat1:i386{a} libffi6:i386{a} libflac8:i386{a} libfontconfig1:i386{a} libfreetype6:i386{a} libgl1-mesa-dri:i386{a} libgl1-mesa-glx:i386{a} libglapi-mesa:i386{a} libglu1-mesa:i386{a} libgmp10:i386{a} libgnutls30:i386{a} libgomp1:i386{a} libgpm2:i386{a} libgsm1:i386{a} libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{a} libhogweed4:i386{a} libice6:i386{a} libicu57:i386{a} libidn11:i386{a} libjack-jackd2-0:i386{a} libjbig0:i386{a} libjpeg62-turbo:i386{a} libk5crypto3:i386{a} libkeyutils1:i386{a} libkrb5-3:i386{a} libkrb5support0:i386{a} liblcms2-2:i386{a} libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} libllvm3.9:i386{a} libltdl7:i386{a} liblzma5:i386{a} libmp3lame0:i386{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} libncurses5:i386{a} libnettle6:i386{a} libnuma1:i386{a} libodbc1:i386{a} libopenal1:i386{a} libopenjp2-7:i386{a} libopus0:i386{a} libosmesa6:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{a} libpcap0.8:i386{a} libpciaccess0:i386{a} libpcre3:i386{a} libpixman-1-0:i386{a} libpng16-16:i386{a} libpulse0:i386{a} libsamplerate0:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a} libsasl2-modules:i386{a} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} libselinux1:i386{a} libsensors4:i386{a} libshine3:i386{a} libsm6:i386{a} libsnappy1v5:i386{a} libsndfile1:i386{a} libsndio6.1:i386{a} libsoxr0:i386{a} libspeex1:i386{a} libspeexdsp1:i386{a} libssl1.1:i386{a} libstdc++6:i386{a} libswresample2:i386{a} libsystemd0:i386{a} libtasn1-6:i386{a} libtheora0:i386{a} libtiff5:i386{a} libtinfo5:i386{a} libtwolame0:i386{a} libtxc-dxtn-s2tc:i386{a} libuuid1:i386{a} libva-drm1:i386{a} libva-x11-1:i386{a} libva1:i386{a} libvdpau-va-gl1:i386{a} libvdpau1:i386{a} libvorbis0a:i386{a} libvorbisenc2:i386{a} libvpx4:i386{a} libwavpack1:i386{a} libwebp6:i386{a} libwebpmux2:i386{a} libwine:i386{a} libwrap0:i386{a} libx11-6:i386{a} libx11-xcb1:i386{a} libx264-148:i386{a} libx265-95:i386{a} libxau6:i386{a} libxcb-dri2-0:i386{a} libxcb-dri3-0:i386{a} libxcb-glx0:i386{a} libxcb-present0:i386{a} libxcb-render0:i386{a} libxcb-shm0:i386{a} libxcb-sync1:i386{a} libxcb1:i386{a} libxcomposite1:i386{a} libxcursor1:i386{a} libxdamage1:i386{a} libxdmcp6:i386{a} libxext6:i386{a} libxfixes3:i386{a} libxi6:i386{a} libxinerama1:i386{a} libxml2:i386{a} libxrandr2:i386{a} libxrender1:i386{a} libxshmfence1:i386{a} libxslt1.1:i386{a} libxtst6:i386{a} libxvidcore4:i386{a} libxxf86vm1:i386{a} libzvbi0:i386{a} mesa-va-drivers:i386{a} mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{a} uuid-runtime{a} va-driver-all:i386{a} vdpau-driver-all:i386{a} wine32:i386 zlib1g:i386{a} The following packages will be upgraded: libavcodec57 libavresample3 libavutil55 libicu57 liblcms2-2 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common libssl1.1 libswresample2 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 libwavpack1 libx11-6 libx11-dev libx11-xcb-dev libx11-xcb1 libxcursor-dev libxcursor1 The following partially installed packages will be configured: libgcc1:i386 19 packages upgraded, 149 newly installed, 0 to remove and 190 not upgraded. Need to get 0 B/96.6 MB of archives. After unpacking 480 MB will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y 
Reading changelogs... Done
Extracting templates from packages: 100% Preconfiguring packages ... (Reading database ... 232711 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.24-11+deb9u3_i386.deb ... Unpacking libc6:i386 (2.24-11+deb9u3) ... dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.24-11+deb9u3_i386.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libc6/NEWS.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libc6:i386 dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) Preparing to unpack .../libpcre3_2%3a8.39-3_i386.deb ... Unpacking libpcre3:i386 (2:8.39-3) ... dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcre3_2%3a8.39-3_i386.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libpcre3/AUTHORS', which is different from other instances of package libpcre3:i386 dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) Preparing to unpack .../liblzma5_5.2.2-1.2+b1_i386.deb ... Unpacking liblzma5:i386 (5.2.2-1.2+b1) ... dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/liblzma5_5.2.2-1.2+b1_i386.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/liblzma5/NEWS.gz', which is different from other instances of package liblzma5:i386 dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) Preparing to unpack .../libselinux1_2.6-3+b3_i386.deb ... Unpacking libselinux1:i386 (2.6-3+b3) ... dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libselinux1_2.6-3+b3_i386.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libselinux1/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libselinux1:i386 Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.24-11+deb9u3_i386.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcre3_2%3a8.39-3_i386.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/liblzma5_5.2.2-1.2+b1_i386.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/libselinux1_2.6-3+b3_i386.deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ... dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgcc1:i386: libgcc1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.2.4); however: Package libc6:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgcc1:i386 (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while processing: libgcc1:i386
```

I also tried `apt-get -f install` as suggested in similar situations online, and I got this.

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done Correcting dependencies... Done The following additional packages will be installed: libc6:i386 Suggested packages: glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386 The following NEW packages will be installed: libc6:i386 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 209 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/2,470 kB of archives. After this operation, 9,803 kB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y Preconfiguring packages ... (Reading database ... 232711 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.24-11+deb9u3_i386.deb ... Unpacking libc6:i386 (2.24-11+deb9u3) ... dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.24-11+deb9u3_i386.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libc6/NEWS.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libc6:i386 dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.24-11+deb9u3_i386.deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After this I tried to use `aptitude update` and got this:

```
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20180310-11:21] stretch InRelease
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20180310-11:21] stretch InRelease
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180310-11:21] stretch InRelease
Err cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20180310-11:21] stretch Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20180310-11:21] stretch Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180310-11:21] stretch Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable InRelease
Hit http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable Release
E: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20180310-11:21] stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20180310-11:21] stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180310-11:21] stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to download some files
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20180310-11:21]/dists/stretch/Release: Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20180310-11:21]/dists/stretch/Release: Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180310-11:21]/dists/stretch/Release: Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried `aptitude upgrade` and got this:

```
Resolving dependencies...                
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firmware-linux-free{a} irqbalance{a} libc6:i386{a} libmicrodns0{a} libprotobuf-lite10{a} 
  libva-wayland1{a} libvlccore9{a} linux-image-4.9.0-8-amd64{a} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  blender blender-data bsdutils ca-certificates chromium chromium-driver cups-ppdc curl 
  discover dnsmasq-base dpkg dpkg-dev ffmpeg file firmware-amd-graphics 
  firmware-linux-nonfree firmware-misc-nonfree firmware-realtek fonts-opensymbol fuse 
  ghostscript gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 git git-man gnupg gnupg-agent gnupg2 gpgv 
  grub-common grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub2-common hdparm imagemagick 
  imagemagick-6-common imagemagick-6.q16 isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common libavcodec57 
  libavdevice57 libavfilter6 libavformat57 libavresample3 libavutil55 libbcmail-java 
  libbcpkix-java libbcprov-java libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libdiscover2 libdom4j-java 
  libdpkg-perl libexiv2-14 libfaad2 libfdisk1 libfuse2 libgd3 libgs9 libgs9-common libicu57 
  libimage-magick-perl libimage-magick-q16-perl libkpathsea6 liblcms2-2 libldap-2.4-2 
  libldap-common liblouis-data liblouis12 libmad0 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libmagick++-6.q16-7 
  libmagickcore-6.q16-3 libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-3 libmspack0 libnm0 
  libokularcore7 libopenmpt-modplug1 libopenmpt0 libpackagekit-glib2-18 
  libpam-kwallet-common libpam-kwallet5 libperl5.24 libpostproc54 libpq5 libptexenc1 
  libpython2.7 libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3.5 libpython3.5-minimal 
  libpython3.5-stdlib libreoffice libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base 
  libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common 
  libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress 
  libreoffice-java-common libreoffice-kde libreoffice-librelogo libreoffice-math 
  libreoffice-nlpsolver libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport 
  libreoffice-report-builder libreoffice-report-builder-bin libreoffice-script-provider-bsh 
  libreoffice-script-provider-js libreoffice-script-provider-python libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb 
  libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql libreoffice-style-breeze libreoffice-style-galaxy 
  libreoffice-wiki-publisher libreoffice-writer libsdl-image1.2 libsdl2-image-2.0-0 
  libserf-1-1 libservlet3.1-java libsmartcols1 libsmbclient libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 
  libssh-4 libssh-gcrypt-4 libssl1.0.2 libssl1.1 libsvn1 libswresample2 libswscale4 
  libsynctex1 libtexlua52 libtexluajit2 libvlc-bin libvlc5 libvncclient1 libvncserver1 
  libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 libvorbisidec1 libwavpack1 libwbclient0 libx11-6 
  libx11-data libx11-dev libx11-doc libx11-xcb-dev libx11-xcb1 libxapian30 libxcursor-dev 
  libxcursor1 libxerces-c3.1 linux-image-amd64 linux-libc-dev network-manager okular 
  openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless openssh-client openssl packagekit packagekit-tools 
  patch perl perl-base perl-modules-5.24 phonon4qt5-backend-vlc python2.7 python2.7-minimal 
  python3-reportbug python3-uno python3.5 python3.5-minimal reportbug samba-libs sddm 
  sddm-theme-debian-maui shared-mime-info subversion systemd-sysv texlive-binaries tzdata 
  uno-libs3 ure util-linux-locales vlc vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-base 
  vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-skins2 vlc-plugin-video-output 
  vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization wget wpasupplicant xdg-utils 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  libgcc1:i386 
The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:
  amd64-microcode dirmngr gnupg-l10n intel-microcode 
208 packages upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/379 MB of archives. After unpacking 201 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
Reading changelogs... Done               
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 232711 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.24-11+deb9u3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libc6:i386 (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.24-11+deb9u3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libc6/NEWS.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libc6:i386
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../bsdutils_1%3a2.29.2-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bsdutils (1:2.29.2-1+deb9u1) over (1:2.29.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.24-11+deb9u3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Setting up bsdutils (1:2.29.2-1+deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgcc1:i386:
 libgcc1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgcc1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgcc1:i386
                                         
Current status: 207 (-1) upgradable.

**dpkg -l libc6**

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold

| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend

|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)

||/ Name               Version        Architecture   Description

+++-==================-==============-==============-==========================================

ii  libc6:amd64        2.24-11+deb9u3 amd64          GNU C Library: Shared libraries

in  libc6:i386         <none>         i386           (no description available)


**apt policy libc6:{amd64,i386}**

libc6:

  Installed: 2.24-11+deb9u3

  Candidate: 2.24-11+deb9u3

  Version table:

 *** 2.24-11+deb9u3 500

        500 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180310-11:21] stretch/main amd64 Packages

        500 http://http.debian.net/debian stable/main amd64 Packages

        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

libc6:i386:

  Installed: (none)

  Candidate: 2.24-11+deb9u3

  Version table:

     2.24-11+deb9u3 500

        500 http://http.debian.net/debian stable/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to this site. To get to your question, [please edit your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/484500/edit) to format the code blocks. We do not need every as many details. Try to stick only to the commands you entered and the error messages you received. The list of the packages and dependencies could either be tidied up or removed. Thank you!

Comment: @kemotep often people don't provide any details. This user, even though they haven't bothered to format their question's code, has at least tried to provide that information.

Comment: Should I get rid of what it was planning on updating and installing ext. ext.?

Comment: Looks like the base C libraries (e.g. `libc6:i386`) are in an inconsistent state wrt. dependency for some reason. What I do in such cases is to use `aptitude`, try to upgrade some "smaller" goal instead of `wine`, maybe upgrade a bunch of libraries manually, and look through conflicts until I have some ideas where the problem is. Sometimes you have to *remove* packages so alternatives can get installed. The UI of aptitude needs some getting used to, though. Sorry, I can't give a step-by-step answer, it really depends on what goes wrong in the dependencies.

Comment: @dirkt they’re inconsistent because they haven’t been upgraded (on `amd64` on this system), but the new installation is using the current version from the repository. This can’t work because multiarch packages need to be upgraded in lockstep and can only be installed if all the versions are identical. So `libc6:amd64` needs to be upgraded before `libc6:i386` can be installed. The repositories themselves are consistent.

Comment: Would it be possible to get the i386 version that matches the ones already installed on my computer from the repository instead of upgrading my amd64 files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your system before attempting the installation again:

```
aptitude update
aptitude upgrade
aptitude install wine32
```

Comment: Debian's current stable version is 9.6.0. Try to use this, this dependency problem might be fixed already. * Using debian mirrors over http is the preferred way, forget dvds.

Comment: I my source.list file for apt is

Comment: deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20180310-11:21]/ stretch contrib main
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20180310-11:21]/ stretch contrib main
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180310-11:21]/ stretch contrib main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free

Comment: The errors related to DVD sources, when you run `aptitude update`, don’t matter. The important part is `aptitude upgrade` — you *need* to get all your packages in sync with the current versions before you can install any multiarch variants (*e.g.* `libc6:i386`).

Comment: After upgrading the applications that needed to be upgraded, and uninstalling all ':i368' packages I found out that libc6:1386 has a problem. It wont install, when I try to install it I get this error:

Comment: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.24-11+deb9u3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libc6/NEWS.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libc6:i386
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.24-11+deb9u3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: It installs libgcc1:i386 properly, but because I depends on  libc6:i386 It is usless

Comment: That error is caused by mismatched `libc6` versions on `amd64` and `i386`. You always need to ensure your system is fully upgraded before installing multiarch packages.

Comment: I have upgraded everything, and it still wont install. And according aptitude versions the amd64 and i386 are the same versions

Comment: And according to aptitude versions, libc6:i386 is pB and libc6 is i. Which if I understand corectly means that libc6 is installed and libc6:i386 is Broken but not installed

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the output of `dpkg -l libc6` and `apt policy libc6:{amd64,i386}`?

Comment: What is the result of running `md5sum /usr/share/doc/libc6/NEWS.Debian.gz`? It should output `5df6d6916a43c802009412f90f63e865  /usr/share/doc/libc6/NEWS.Debian.gz`.

Comment: I get: `e0ca9fd7160343ee834ead44b9b565c9  /usr/share/doc/libc6/NEWS.Debian.gz`

Comment: Ah, that might be it then... `apt --reinstall install libc6` should help.

Comment: I just needed to `apt --reinstall install` all the amd64 packages for the i386 packages that woudn't install. Thanks!